# Running command on multiple servers

Tags: windows

I would like to run a basic command on multiple servers by using a response file, similar to your [How to ping multiple servers and return their IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332776/3604386) command.  I can run the command from my workstation and it returns all of the information just fine.

```
schtasks /query /v /fo csv /nh >> \\my-pc\c$\temp\details_sched_tasks.csv
```

Comment: have you tried an automated ssh query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option worked best.

**Detailed Views of Scheduled Tasks**

- Create a file named server_list.txt and supply all the names of the servers you wish to run the command against.
- Log onto a server in the domain you wish to run the command against.
- Place the file into a directory like d:\temp or even just the root of d:\
- Open a command prompt and go to the same directory you have your list of servers.
- Copy/paste the below command into the command window and hit enter.

for /f %x in (server_list.txt) do (schtasks /query /s %x /v /fo csv /nh >> d:\sched d:\sched_tasks.csv)

Answer (score 2):

[PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) supports a text list of computer names or IPs as an argument.

Example:

```
psexec /u domain\adminguy @computerlist.txt \\server\share\command_to_run.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

Could port your servers to a list using dsquery, then use psexec to execute the schtask on the remote computer using the output. It would look something like this.

```
dsquery computer ou=serverOU,dc=microsoft,dc=com* -o rdn > list.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('type list.txt') DO psexec \\%%a schtasks /query /v /fo csv /nh >> \\my-pc\c$\temp\details_sched_tasks.csv
```